# Laravel 7 export value from ajax to blade to for loop through json

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax call from DB in JSON response like

```
0: {id: 1, name: "nancy", cost: 100, quantity: 4, barcode: 12345, category_id: 1,…}
1: {id: 3, name: "elissa", cost: 60, quantity: 3, barcode: 98987, category_id: 1,…}
2: {id: 4, name: "nancy", cost: 100, quantity: 32, barcode: 99999, category_id: 1,…}
3: {id: 7, name: "new one", cost: 200, quantity: 12, barcode: 66778, category_id: 1,…}
4: {id: 10, name: "new begama", cost: 70, quantity: 6, barcode: 10001, category_id: 1,…}
```

and I got the length

```
success: function (result) {//alert(typeof (result)); alert(result.length);) }),
```

how can I forloop on them in Blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop over these strictly in `blade` you will need to pass `HTML` back in the response instead of `JSON`. Otherwise you will have no choice but to loop over them in `JS`.

For example you'd need to create a view file which has something like this:

Make the a view with the following html in it, then put the path of this new file in the controller method below.

```
    @foreach($data as $item)
        {{$item->name}}
    @endforeach
```

Then in your controller you'd do something like this:

```
    public function salesHiddenCoffee(Request $request)
    {
        $category_id = $request->get('category_id');
        $products = Product::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();

        $view = view('make.a.view.the.html.above.in.it.then.put.the.path.here', ['products' => $products]);
        $html = $view->render();

        return ['success' => true, 'html' => $html];
    }
```

You would of course need to change your JS to digest the `HTML` response.

```
success: function (result) {
    if(result.html != undefined) {
        $(container_you_want_the_html_to_go).html(result.html);
    }
}),
```

**Alternatively**

```
let container = $('#ID_of_your_container');
$.each(result, function (i, item) {
    $(container).append('<div>' + item.name + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: i have in mane view select tag of Category. on depending on it calling ajax to view owned products

Comment: it's possible to used render() , or write a template in jquery and  use appendTo() ???

Comment: It sounds like you're overcomplicating this a little - could you share your controller method code?

Comment: ```    public function salesHiddenCoffee(Request $request)
    {
        $category_id = $request->get('category_id');
        //dd($category_id);

        $products = Product::where('category_id', 'LIKE', $category_id)->get();
        return response()->json($products);
    }```

Comment: u mean I had to create a new view blade and make a template for products, Then render a view to the main view?

Comment: Firstly, make that new view, with the 3 lines of code (the loop). Once you have done that, you DO NOT include it anywhere. This is in addition to the page you're currently using. The JavaScript ajax request will be given `['success' => true, 'html' => $html]` after going to that controller method. In your JavaScript you will now have `result.html` present. You can use `result.html` to include the `rendered view` from the controller, as the loop is now inside this `result.html` variable. I.e: `$(container_you_want_the_html_to_go).html(result.html);`

Comment: ok I understand, Thank you very much for your time,  I will try The code now